# ValueChangeEvent fires in IE7 & IE8 only after 2nd click

Tags: jsf-2, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, myfaces

Here is the code from .xhtml page:

```
<h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{searchModel.setSelectedSearchItem}" value="#{searchModel.selectedSearchItemName}" 
    layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItems value="#{searchModel.searchParametersNames}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}" />
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="searchPane messagesPane" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

And corresponding method signature:

```
public void setSelectedSearchItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    //do smth...
}
```

It works just fine in Chrome, FF and IE9+. The problem with IE7 & IE8 is that ValueChangeEvent fires not after radioButton is clicked (1st click), but after I click once more some other place on the page (2nd click). Any chance I can make ValueChangeEvent to fire after 1st click in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: Does it have a value set before the first click?

Comment: No. Don't think that's the case - if I choose one option (and make 2nd click of course), then it will have a value, but still event will be fired on next 2nd click only.

Comment: Try to set a value on start up and check again: does it work?

Comment: Nope. Still IE7 & IE8 fire event only after one more click anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this problem. Added

```
onclick="this.blur()"
```

here

```
<h:selectOneRadio valueChangeListener="#{searchModel.setSelectedSearchItem}" value="#{searchModel.selectedSearchItemName}" 
     layout="pageDirection" onclick="this.blur()">
```

and now event fires when needed in IE7 & IE8!